# "Global variable is undefined at the module level" is the error I get but it only happend when I run the program from pycharm and not from Jupyter

Tags: python, undefined, nameerror

```
import wordcloud
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
import fileupload
import io
import sys

def _upload():


    _upload_widget = fileupload.FileUploadWidget()

    def _cb(change):
        global file_contents
        decoded = io.StringIO(change['owner'].data.decode('utf-8'))
        filename = change['owner'].filename
        print('Uploaded `{}` ({:.2f} kB)'.format(
            filename, len(decoded.read()) / 2 **10))
        file_contents = decoded.getvalue()

    _upload_widget.observe(_cb, names='data')
    display(_upload_widget)

_upload()
...

myimage = calculate_frequencies(file_contents)
plt.imshow(myimage, interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

This is the error I get on pycharm:

```
myimage = calculate_frequencies(file_contents)
NameError: name 'file_contents' is not defined
FileUploadWidget(label='Browse', _dom_classes=('widget_item', 'btn-group'))
```

Comment: Does the `...` contain a definition of `file_contents`? Presumably not, and that's why you're getting the error. `file_contents = decoded.getvalue()` in `_upload` is a _local variable_ that's deleted upon return from `_upload`

Comment: The cause is not apparent in the code you shared.  On which line of code are you getting the error?  Please provide the full error handling stack.

As an example, the following code works find in PyCharm for me.

def global_example():
    global my_var
    my_var = 1
    return 3


print(global_example())
print(my_var)